# Is it possible to pass an object as a parameter to a function without copying it?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Look at this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Entity {
public:
    Entity(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {std::cout << "DEFAULT\n";}

    Entity(const Entity& that) {
        std::cout << "COPY\n";
        this->x = that.x;
        this->y = that.y;
    }

    Entity(Entity&& that) {
        std::cout << "MOVE\n";
        this->x = that.x;
        this->y = that.y;
    }

private:
    int x, y;

};

class List {
public:
    List(){vec.reserve(25);}

    void Add(Entity &&en) {
        vec.emplace_back(std::move(en)); //invokes the move constructor
    }
    
    void Add(int x, int y) {
        vec.emplace_back(x, y);
    }

private:
    std::vector<Entity> vec;

};

int main() {
    List L;
    L.Add(Entity(10, 20));
    L.Add(100, 200);

    return 0;
}
```

I've defined a vector of type `Entity` inside the `List` class and provided a function `Add()` to access this vector. Using the `Add(Entity&&)` overload invokes the move constructor meanwhile using the other overload, `Add(int, int)` doesn't trigger anything but the default constructor of `Entity`.

I know why `Add(int, int)` doesn't invoke copy or move constructors. Because `std::vector::emplace_back()` utilizes the placement new operator to create the object in-place.

But I don't understand the behavior of the `Add(Entity&&)` function. Why is the object getting moved? Is it because it has been created outside of the stack frame of the calling function? If so and if it's possible, how to avoid moving the object?

If I'm totally wrong, please clarify it for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course you could create an object on the heap (`std::make_unique`) and just pass the `std::unique_ptr` pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
L.Add(Entity(10, 20));
```

the following operations happen:

```
Entity(10, 20) creates a temporary
List::add is called with temporary
std::move() makes the temporary movable
vector::emplace_back is called with the temporary
vector resizes
vector calls construct_at with the temporary
construct_at calls placement new with the temporary
placement new copies/moves the temporary into place
```

Now the compiler elides all of that except these three things:

```
Entity(10, 20) creates a temporary
vector resizes
placement new copies/moves constructs the temporary
```

Unfortunately the compiler does not elide the copy/move construction in the `new` call. Unlike `Entity(Entity(10, 20))`, where the copy/move construct is optimized out, the `new(addr) Entity(Entity(10, 20))` your code basically comes to does not collapse in the same way.

It would be nice if the compiler would (could?) optimize the extra copy/move construct away but it's not defined for `new` to do that.

Answer (score 2):

With `emplace_back` you provide arguments that can be directly passed to the `Entity::Entity(int,int)` constructor.

When you already have an object of type `Entity` your only option is to pass that object to the constructor. The only 2 constructors that take a parameter of  type `Entity` are the copy and the move constructor. The move constructor is chosen because you pass an rvalue (via `std::move`)

> how to avoid moving the object?

If you already have the object then the only 2 options are copy or move. What else could there be? If you have the individual parameters needed to construct the object (like your `int`, `int`) then you can use `emplace_back` like you do in that case.